# determing the limit of size of the array when writing CUDA kernel for multi-gpu using Thrust library

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I am trying to write a CUDA kernel which will use multi-gpu and thrust library features. I used some tips from some previous posts.I tried to write a simple addition kernel. My obvious intention is to use more complicated kernels.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{      
    int num_gpus = 0;   // number of CUDA GPUs
    // determine the number of CUDA capable GPUs
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_gpus);
    printf("number of CUDA devices:\t%d\n", num_gpus);

    typedef thrust::device_vector<int> dvec;
    typedef dvec *p_dvec;

    // Declaring Vectors
    std::vector<p_dvec> dvecs1;
    std::vector<p_dvec> dvecs2;
    std::vector<p_dvec> dvecs3;
    std::vector<double>p(num_gpus);
    dim3 DimGrid((DSIZE-1)/16.0 +1,1,1);
    dim3 DimBlock(16.0,1,1);

    // Initialize Vectors
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_gpus; i++) {
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        p_dvec temp1 = new dvec(DSIZE);
        dvecs1.push_back(temp1);
        thrust::fill((*(dvecs1[i])).begin(),(*(dvecs1[i])).end(),1.0);
        p_dvec temp2 = new dvec(DSIZE);
        dvecs2.push_back(temp2);
        thrust::fill((*(dvecs2[i])).begin(),(*(dvecs2[i])).end(),2.0);
    }

  // Launching The Kernel
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < num_gpus; i++) {
      cudaSetDevice(i);
      p_dvec temp = new dvec(DSIZE);
      dvecs3.push_back(temp);
      fooKernel<<<DimGrid,DimBlock>>>(convertToKernel(*dvecs1[i])),convertToKernel(*(dvecs2[i])),convertToKernel(*(dvecs3[i])));
      // Reduction Operation
      p[i]= thrust::reduce((*(dvecs3[i])).begin(),(*(dvecs3[i])).end(), (double) 0, thrust::plus<double>());
      std::cout<<*((*(dvecs3[i])).begin())<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
  }

  printf("Success\n");
  return 0;  
}
```

and the header file is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>   
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#define DSIZE 1048560                                  

template < typename T >                                                        
struct    KernelArray                                                             
{                                                                              
  T*  _array;                                                                
  int _size;                                                                 
};                                                 

// Function to convert device_vector to structure                              
template < typename T >                                                        
KernelArray< T > convertToKernel( thrust::device_vector< T >& dVec )           
{                                                                              
    KernelArray< T > kArray;                                                   
    kArray._array = thrust::raw_pointer_cast( &dVec[0] );                      
    kArray._size  = ( int ) dVec.size();                                       

    return kArray;                                                             
}                                                                              

template< typename scalartype>                                                 
__global__ void fooKernel( KernelArray< scalartype > Array1, KernelArray<scalartype>Array2, KernelArray<scalartype> Array3)
{
  size_t i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;                            
  if(i< DSIZE)
  Array3._array[i] = Array2._array[i] +Array1._array[i];                       

}
```

Now if DSIZE> 1048560, then the result is 0; 
I have few questions:

1)How to determine the size limit of the vector. I have 8 devices.

2)Is there any way to increase the size of the data that I can use or improve the code?

3)When and where do I need cudaDeviceSynchronize() ?

I would be happy if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

If you had used [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api/14038590#14038590) to find out if and which CUDA errors occured, you would have gotten the following output after launching `fooKernel` with `DSIZE > 1048560`:

```
invalid argument
```

The reason for this error is that you can have [at most 65535 blocks in one dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9841310/678093) and

```
1048560/16 = 65535
```

So you did not run into a size limit of the vector but into the maximum block limit.